# ExpandableRecyclerView - How to expand and collapse multiple CardViews simultaneously

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-button, android-cardview

Is it possible to expand and collapse multiple `CardView`s within a `RecyclerView` at the same time? I created a header (for my RecyclerView) with two buttons but I'm not sure what needs to go in the click event.

[image]

[image]

**RecyclerView adapter class**

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    public boolean isSupposedToBeCollapsed;

    private Context mContext;

    RecyclerViewHeader header;
    List<RecyclerViewItem> listItems;
    ValueAnimator mAnimator;



    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, RecyclerViewHeader header, List<RecyclerViewItem> listItems)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.header = header;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_header, parent, false);
            return new MyRecyclerAdapter.VHHeader(v);
        }
        else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
            return new MyRecyclerAdapter.VHItem(v);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    private RecyclerViewItem getItem(int position)
    {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(mContext, FontManager.FONTAWESOME);

        if (holder instanceof VHHeader)
        {
            final VHHeader vhHeader = (VHHeader)holder;

            vhHeader.btnExpandAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isSupposedToBeCollapsed){
                    // change visibility to 'VISIBLE'
                    txtB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // change direction of chevron to 'up'
                    txtExpandCollapse.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_up);

                    // apply animation to the height of 'txtB'
                    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, textBHeight);

                    // start the animation
                    mAnimator.start();
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                }
            });

            vhHeader.btnCollapseAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isSupposedToBeCollapsed){
                        // change visibility to 'VISIBLE'
                        txtB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        // change direction of chevron to 'up'
                        txtExpandCollapse.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_up);

                        // apply animation to the height of 'txtB'
                        mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, textBHeight);

                        // start the animation
                        mAnimator.start();
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else if (holder instanceof VHItem)
        {

            RecyclerViewItem currentItem = getItem(position-1);
            final VHItem vhItem = (VHItem)holder;

            vhItem.txtA.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
            vhItem.txtB.setText(currentItem.getDescription());

            vhItem.txtB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            vhItem.txtExpandCollapse.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_down);
            vhItem.txtExpandCollapse.setTypeface(iconFont);

            //Add onPreDrawListener
            vhItem.txtB.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    vhItem.txtB.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    vhItem.txtB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    vhItem.txtB.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                    vhItem.textBHeight = vhItem.txtB.getMeasuredHeight();

                    return true;
                }
            });

            vhItem.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(vhItem.txtB.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                        vhItem.expand();
                    } else {
                        vhItem.collapse();
                    }
                }
            });

            vhItem.mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(vhItem.txtB.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                        vhItem.expand();
                    } else {
                        vhItem.collapse();
                    }
                }
            });

            vhItem.txtExpandCollapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(vhItem.txtB.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                        vhItem.expand();
                    } else {
                        vhItem.collapse();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // need to override this method
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
            return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position)
    {
        return position == 0;
    }

    // increasing getItemcount to 1. This will be the row of header.
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size()+1;
    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        Button btnCollapseAll, btnExpandAll;

        public VHHeader(View headerView) {
            super(headerView);

            this.btnCollapseAll = headerView.findViewById(R.id.btn_collapseall);
            this.btnExpandAll = headerView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expandall);
        }
    }

    public class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cardView;
        LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
        TextView txtExpandCollapse, txtA, txtB;
        public int textBHeight;

        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            this.mLinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_tconnections_titlerow);
            this.mRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_relativelayout);
            this.mRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);
            this.txtExpandCollapse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_expandcollapse);
            this.txtA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_A);
            this.txtB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_B);
        }

        private void expand() {
            // change visibility to 'VISIBLE'
            txtB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // change direction of chevron to 'up'
            txtExpandCollapse.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_up);

            // apply animation to the height of 'txtB'
            mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, textBHeight);

            // start the animation
            mAnimator.start();
        }

        private void collapse() {
            // change direction of chevron to 'down'
            txtExpandCollapse.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_down);

            int finalHeight = txtB.getHeight();

            ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

            mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    txtB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
                }
            });
            mAnimator.start();
        }


        public ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);


            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    // update height
                    int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = txtB.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = value;
                    txtB.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
            });
            return animator;
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), getHeader(), getListItems());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    public RecyclerViewHeader getHeader()
    {
        return new RecyclerViewHeader();
    }

    public List<RecyclerViewItem> getListItems()
    {
        List<RecyclerViewItem> rvItems = new ArrayList<>();

        RecyclerViewItem itemA = new RecyclerViewItem();
        itemA.setConnectionMode("Item A");
        itemA.setConnectionName("Feature A1");
        rvItems.add(itemA);

        RecyclerViewItem itemB = new RecyclerViewItem();
        itemB.setConnectionMode("Item B");
        itemB.setConnectionName("Feature B1\nFeature B2");
        rvItems.add(itemB);

        RecyclerViewItem itemC = new RecyclerViewItem();
        itemC.setConnectionMode("Item C");
        itemC.setConnectionName("Feature C1\nFeature C2\nFeature C3");
        rvItems.add(itemC);


        return rvItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. What you can do is, set a variable(boolean) that stores the state of the card (expanded/collapsed) in the RecyclerAdapter code.
2. Then, in your onBindViewHolder code block, write a piece of code to check if the card should be expanded or collapsed using the above-mentioned variable and the required display code.

Example:

```
if(isSuppossedToBeCollapsed){
    textView.setVisibility = false;
}
else{
    textView.setVisibility = true;
}
```

3. You can then call notifyDatasetChanged in your RecyclerAdapter code to update the recycler views when you click the button which will redraw the views and reflect the state of the cards(expanded/collapsed) accordingly.

[NotifyDatasetChanged Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged)

Comment: @MacaronLover notifyDatasetChanged is an inbuilt function for a recycler adapter. You can call notifyDatasetChanged() from within the onBindViewHolder code block... There is no code per se for notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: @MacaronLover I've added a link to the documentation of notifyDatasetChanged in the answer, in case you wanna go through it...

Comment: Which area of the code does notifyDatasetChanged need to go? Step 2 I can't seem to get working because the TextView is not in the header - it is in the RecyclerView item.

Comment: @MacaronLover Sorry for the late reply, bro... Notifydatasetchanged needs to go in expand all and collapse all button's on click listeners... Let the Boolean variable be a global variable in the RecyclerAdapter class... The text view doesn't need to be in the header... Basically, in the else if (holder instance of VHItem) add if(globalvariable == true){vhItem.expand()} else{vhItem.collapse ()} So whenever the view holder is drawn, the global variable is checked and the views are collapsed or expanded accordingly...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've spent the whole week trying to get the code right, but 'm still a bit lost as I'm not sure of the correct place to add the `notifyDatasetChanged` code. I have added the updated Java code for my `RecyclerView` adapter and fragment classes + the error code in red.